# Any way to know error details in Ansible / AWX even when we have a no_log: true for the task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

We have an Ansible automation in production which talks to a remote API. When we check the logs of that task in AWX, it reveals a lot of sensitive data like the API key, hence we have removed the logging by adding `no_log: true` for that task.

Now, we need to know the cause of the error when the task fails, but the `no_log` setting prevents us from seeing any valuable logs. Is there a way to save the error JSON logs in a file on the backend server (only accessible to admins), so that when that remote API task fails, we can troubleshoot using the logs?
Since the AWX instance is accessible to non-admins as well, we cannot rollback `no_log` to false, to avoid revealing sensitive data.

We normally have to disable the `no_log` setting temporarily, and re-run the job, but this is not ideal.

Comment: Can you provide Information what caused the errors mostly in the past? Were there a specific set or class where the error came from?

Comment: One such error in the past was that the backend server had a component down, while at one occasion, we were out of license units for the 3rd party vendor API , and hence the jobs were failing.  Exceptional / rare scenarios mostly, but we would like to have them written to a log file if possible, and be able to fix quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use [a `block` and rescue the error](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks) of the API, log its registered output, then fail with a convenient message for the end user.

*Please mind:* you **have to [*delegate*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)** the `copy` task creating the file if you want the error to be logged in the controller (the AWX machine, in your case) and not on the targeted node(s).

Here is an example of such a block:

```yaml
- block:
    - uri:
        url: "http://username:{{ secret_password | urlencode }}@example.org"
      no_log: true
      register: uri_output

  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        log: "/var/log/ansible-failure-{{ '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' |  strftime }}.log"

    - copy:
        content: "{{ uri_output | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: "{{ log }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

    - fail:
        msg: |-
          The exact error has been redacted due to secret information,
          but have been logged in `{{ log }}`.
          If you do not have sufficient rights, please ask an administrator.
```

Which, on success, would yield:

```yaml
TASK [uri] ***************************************************************
ok: [ansible-node]
```

But in case of error:

```yaml
TASK [uri] ***************************************************************
fatal: [ansible-node]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  censored: 'the output has been hidden due to the fact that ''no_log: true'' was specified for this result'

TASK [set_fact] **********************************************************
ok: [ansible-node]

TASK [copy] **************************************************************
changed: [ansible-node -> localhost]

TASK [fail] **************************************************************
fatal: [ansible-node]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: |-
    The exact error has been redacted due to secret information,
    but have been logged in `/var/log/ansible-failure-20230908100134.log`.
    If you do not have sufficient rights, please ask an administrator.
```

Along with the file */var/log/ansible-failure-20230908100134.log*, containing:

```json
{
    "changed": false,
    "elapsed": 0,
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>",
    "redirected": false,
    "status": -1,
    "url": "http://username:shh%20I%20am%20a%20secret@example.org"
}
```